# Why does sscanf result in 0 in this case?

Tags: c

I am trying to convert a series of decimal numbers to their hex representation in string format and then back from string to decimal. This might sound strange but is a simplified representation of a more complex situation.
So, either way, I have the following piece of code which almost works fine. For some reason my variable a is still equal to 0 at the end while it should equal  43, all the other variables seem to be alright:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    /********************* A *******************/
    uint16_t a = 43;   //0x002b 
    int16_t  b = -43;  //0xffd5
    uint32_t c = 234;  //0x000000ea
    int32_t d = -234;  //0xffffff16

    char aStr[10]={0};
    char bStr[10]={0};
    char cStr[10]={0};
    char dStr[10]={0};

    snprintf(aStr, sizeof(aStr), "%04hhx", a);
    snprintf(bStr, sizeof(bStr), "%04x", b & 0xFFFF);
    snprintf(cStr, sizeof(cStr), "%08hhx", c);
    snprintf(dStr, sizeof(aStr), "%08x", d & 0xFFFFFFFF);

    fprintf(stdout, "TX a = %s.\n", aStr);
    fprintf(stdout, "TX b = %s.\n", bStr);
    fprintf(stdout, "TX c = %s.\n", cStr);
    fprintf(stdout, "TX d = %s.\n", dStr);

    /********************* B *******************/

    uint16_t aOut = 0;
    int16_t bOut = 0;
    uint32_t cOut = 0;
    int32_t dOut = 0;

    sscanf(aStr, "%04hhx", &aOut);
    sscanf(bStr, "%04x", &bOut);
    sscanf(cStr, "%08hhx", &cOut);
    sscanf(dStr, "%08x", &dOut);

    fprintf(stdout, "rx a = %d\n", aOut);  //<---- this line prints 0 for a. Why?
    fprintf(stdout, "rx b = %d\n", bOut);
    fprintf(stdout, "rx c = %d\n", cOut);
    fprintf(stdout, "rx d = %d\n", dOut);

    return 0;
}
```

Does anybody know why or what I am missing?

Comment: Try changing `uint16_t a = 43;` to `uint16_t a = 0xAA55;` and see what you get.

Comment: Compiler warnings are your friend. https://godbolt.org/z/6aa4oY9eq

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/12149471)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
sscanf(aStr, "%04hhx", &aOut);
```

is wrong. The `%hhx` conversion format specifier requires an argument of type `unsigned char *`, but you are instead passing it an argument of type `uint16_t *`. This invokes undefined behavior.

I suggest that you change that line to the following:

```
sscanf(aStr, "%04"SCNx16, &aOut);
```

On most platforms, the macro `SCNx16` will simply expand to `"hx"`, but it is generally safer to use the macro, in case you code happens to be running on a (future) platform on which `uint16_t` is not equivalent to an `unsigned short`.

The lines

```
sscanf(bStr, "%04x", &bOut);
sscanf(cStr, "%08hhx", &cOut);
sscanf(dStr, "%08x", &dOut);
```

are also using the wrong conversion format specifiers. I recommend that you use the following code instead:

```
sscanf(bStr, "%04"SCNx16, &bOut);
sscanf(cStr, "%08"SCNx32, &cOut);
sscanf(dStr, "%08"SCNx32, &dOut);
```

Strictly speaking, the above code also invokes undefined behavior, because the `%x` conversion format specifier requires a pointer to an `unsigned` type instead of to a `signed` type. However, this should not be a problem in practice, provided that the converted value can be represented both in the `signed` type and in the `unsigned` type.

Comment: "Stricly speaking, the above code also invokes undefined behavior, because the %x conversion format specifier requires a pointer to an unsigned type instead of to a signed type" Interesting statement. From where do you get that, the C standard?

Comment: @LandonZeKepitelOfGreytBritn: Yes, it is undefined behavior according to [§7.21.6.2 ¶10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p10) and ¶12 of the ISO C11 standard. According to ¶12, when using `%x`, the "corresponding argument shall be a pointer to unsigned integer".

Comment: Just noticed your answer is actually wrong I think. [Based on this](https://www.carta.tech/man-pages/man3/SCNx16.3avr.html) SCNx is only for unsigned scanning. Not signed scanning. Weirdly enough there does not seem to be hex scanning for signed values.

Comment: @Landon: Yes, you are correct that strictly speaking, my solution does invoke undefined behavior, which makes it "wrong" in a sense. I have already pointed this out in my answer, in the sentence that you quoted in your first comment. However, I also pointed out in my answer that this is not an issue in practice. The only solution that strictly conforms with the standard would be to first write the converted value to an object with an `unsigned` data type and then to cast it to a `signed` data type.

Comment: @Landon: To elaborate on my previous statement that this is not an issue in practice: [The compiler gcc only provides a warning about a signed/unsigned mismatch if I enable strict ISO compliance mode](https://godbolt.org/z/nhb719Mxn). The compiler clang does not warn at all, even if I enable strict ISO compliance mode.